# RecyclerView causes "Resource Not found" exception in long list

Tags: android, xamarin

I have this OnBindViewHolder:

```
public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            PlayerBalanceRecycleView view = holder as PlayerBalanceRecycleView;
            var item = mItems[position];

            view.Date.Text = item.CreationDate.ToString("dd/MM");
            view.Result.Text = item.Amount.ToString("N0", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
            view.Total.Text = item.Balance.ToString("N0", new CultureInfo("en-US"));



            /* Remove SessionDetailed */
            //var oldFrag = mFragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag("session_" + view.SessionDetailed.Id);
            //if (oldFrag != null) mFragmentManager.BeginTransaction().Remove(oldFrag).Commit();

            /* Create new ID and Tag */
            //var newId = Utils.GenerateViewId();
            var tag = "session_" + view.SessionDetailed.Id.ToString();
            //view.SessionDetailed.Id = newId;

            if (item.Type == PlayerBalanceItemTypes.Payment)
            {
                view.Icon.SetImageDrawable(mActivity.Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.ic_money_medium_blue));
                view.Result.SetTextColor(mActivity.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.blue));
            }
            else if (item.Type == PlayerBalanceItemTypes.Session)
            {
                view.Icon.SetImageDrawable(mActivity.Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.ic_chips_medium));
                view.Result.SetTextColor(mActivity.Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.orange));

                var frag = new BalancePlayerSession(item);

                var trans = mFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
                trans.Replace(view.SessionDetailed.Id, frag, tag);
                trans.Commit();

            }
            if (item.Type == PlayerBalanceItemTypes.InitialDebt)
                view.Date.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;

            view.SessionDetailed.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        }
```

All ID's are unique and set in the OnCreateViewHolder. In shorter lists (ones that doesn't go beyond the screen) works just fine. However, when the list goes beyond the screen it causes a "Resource Not Found" exception and refering to the Unique ID that I set.

It seems that the actual View are not created (so that you can scroll "on-demand").

OnCreateViewHolder:

```
public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            View row = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.balance_player_row, parent, false);
            LinearLayout mRoot = row.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.layoutPlayerBalance);
            ImageView mIcon = row.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageViewPlayerBalanceType);
            TextView mDate = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textBalancePlayerDate);
            TextView mResult = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textBalancePlayerResult);
            TextView mTotal = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textBalancePlayerTotal);
            LinearLayout mSessionDetailed = row.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.layoutBalancePlayerSessionDetailed);
            mSessionDetailed.Id = Utils.GenerateViewId();

            PlayerBalanceRecycleView view = new PlayerBalanceRecycleView(row)
            {
                View = row,
                Root = mRoot,
                Icon = mIcon,
                Date = mDate,
                Result = mResult,
                Total = mTotal,
                SessionDetailed = mSessionDetailed
            };

            view.SetClickListener(OnClick);

            return view;
        }
```

Video explaning the behavior: https://sendvid.com/qi1efjwd

How can I make sure that the Fragment is replacing the View correctly?

Comment: Please include a sample project demonstrating the issue with a couple of screenshots showing the behaviors!

Comment: @JonDouglas Thanks for your commente. I added a link to a video showing what happens. For the first user it works as expected but not for the second user where the list is longer than the screen. I will create a sample project as well and upload.